# More efficient way to write this Jquery code

Tags: jquery

Is there a better, more efficient way to write this code?  It's a make shift drop down menu that allows user to RSVP for multiple people.  Sorry, it's kind of a mess, but I think what I'm doing is clear.  If not, I'm at my computer and will respond quickly with more info need be.

```
 //There's got to be a better way to do this
 $('#guest_num_1').click( function() {
 $('#num_guests a#quant_guests').html("1")
 $('.guest_name_2, .guest_name_3, .guest_name_4, .guest_name_5, .guest_name_6 ').hide()
 });

 $('#guest_num_2').click( function() {
 $('#num_guests a#quant_guests').html("2")
 $('.guest_name_2').fadeIn()
 $('.guest_name_3, .guest_name_4, .guest_name_5, .guest_name_6').hide()
 });

 $('#guest_num_3').click( function() {
 $('#num_guests a#quant_guests').html("3")
 $('.guest_name_2, .guest_name_3').fadeIn()
 $('.guest_name_4, .guest_name_5, .guest_name_6').hide()
 });

 $('#guest_num_4').click( function() {
 $('#num_guests a#quant_guests').html("4")
 $('.guest_name_2, .guest_name_3, .guest_name_4').fadeIn()
 $('.guest_name_5, .guest_name_6').hide()
 });

 $('#guest_num_5').click( function() {
 $('#num_guests a#quant_guests').html("5")
 $('.guest_name_2, .guest_name_3, .guest_name_4, .guest_name_5').fadeIn()
 $('.guest_name_6').hide()
 });

 $('#guest_num_6').click( function() {
 $('#num_guests a#quant_guests').html("6")
 $('.guest_name_2, .guest_name_3, .guest_name_4, .guest_name_5, .guest_name_6').fadeIn()
 });
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm such a beginner to all this that this was the best I could put together.  It seems like it has SO much redundancy.

Comment: That depends on your HTML code too. I think, your markup can also be improved and then your JS can be improved.

Comment: so you want to click on a 'number of guests' option, fade in the guest names up to that number, and fade out the guest names after that number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.guest_num').click(function() {
  var n = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
  $('#num_guests a#quant_guests').html(n);
  var curr = $('.guest_name_' + n);
  curr.prevAll().fadeIn();
  curr.fadeIn();
  curr.nextAll().hide();
  return false;
});
```

On the HTML side:

```
<a class="guest_num" href="#1">...</a>
```

Comment: +1 I was in the middle of writing out pretty much this exact code. :]

Comment: @ghoppe `curr.prevAll()` does not include `curr`. Check: http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Comment: @Fábio thanks I was confused in my testing as I chained the `curr.fadeIn().prevAll().fadeIn();` to save a line. oops. I'll delete my misguided comment.

Comment: OK, a better way to save a line: `curr.prevAll().andSelf().fadeIn();`

Answer (score -1):

use a loop and store this "guest_num_1" and for every eteration change the '1' with the loop index